# Page not found for file jquery-ui.css

Tags: jquery, dialog, http-status-code-404

I need to display a dialog box on a button click, i choose jquery for  this purpose, but i am facing following error:

```
1. GET http://localhost:8080/ReportFetcher/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jquery-ui-themes-1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css 404 (Not Found) 
2. GET http://localhost:8080/ReportFetcher/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jquery-1.10.1.js 404 (Not Found) 
3. GET http://localhost:8080/ReportFetcher/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jquery-ui.js 404 (Not Found)
4. GET http://localhost:8080/resources/demos/style.css 404 (Not Found)
```

Location where i placed these files in my project is:
   /ReportFetcher ---> WebContent---> WEBINF-->lib---> ( here i place all the above mentioned files and folder (jquery-ui-themes-1.10.3/themes).

I could not understand why browser is not getting the above mentioned resource.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="/ReportFetcher/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jquery-ui-themes-1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="/ReportFetcher/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script src="/ReportFetcher/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#trail").click(function() {
            $("#dialog").dialog();
        });
    });
....
some more code here
```

When i use

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
```

everything goes well.
But my application should work without internet connection too.

Comment: `WEB-INF/lib` seems a funny place to put resources that are supposed to be accessed from the browser. If you placed "all the above mentioned files" there why is the `style.css` href set to `/resources/demos`?

Comment: @nnnnnn Then what should be the appropriate place to place all resources. Since i am new may be that's why i made funny mistake. Could you please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-themes-1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

and placing the file in

> WebContent

resolves the issue for me.

Refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp) for some explaination

Comment: If there exists a better way then please share them with me